# how to make perfect UPS for Arduino?

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, lipo, ups, tp4056

Well I am trying to make UPS, uninterruptible power supply, for Arduino Leonardo. This is my circuit

[image]

I am using for lipo chargher this ICs, it use [TC4056A](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1309136/FUMANELECTRONICS/TC4056A/1) and [DW01](https://ic-fortune.com/upload/Download/DW01x-DS-17_EN_53550.pdf) . I think main problem is **DW01 overdischarging protection**

[image]

I have read documents [TC4056A](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1309136/FUMANELECTRONICS/TC4056A/1) and changed the R3 resistor to 2.4k Ohm to decrease charging current to approximately 500 mA to prevent much more heating. Charging and mean time Arduino working properly there is no problem. if I plug out the my UPS. Battery start supplying Arduino. But the problem is if battery was totally finished (all lamp's of battery level switch off and Arduino stopped). Battery can not start charging when I plug in the system. I'm measuring the current from type-c side it shows 40mA but I know while normally working it should be 500mA or more. If I plug out the Arduino from UPS battery starts to charging and measuring current goes 500mA. After waiting a moment, If I plug in the Arduino charging goes normally and arduino start to work.

Well I know, I can not good tell my problem. I take refuge in your understanding.

Well I have try to add circuit.

[image]

**NEW ADDED**

after watching [this video](https://youtu.be/joAkJ9QA2bw?t=540) I understood the problem! the problem is if the battery voltage lower than 3 volts, lipo charger IC will consume only 50mA. I need to remove load until lipo battery voltage level up to 3 volts.

**So question was changed! How can remove the load ( at this project "Arduino Leonardo") until lipo battery level over then 3 volts?**

Comment: No, that's a picture of your hardware and not a circuit or schematic. A schematic is required.

Comment: If you discharge the battery too far, below a certain voltage, the LTC4056 will not start charging at the full current, but with a smaller current, until the battery's voltage has risen enough to start the normal charging cycle. You could try to see if, given time, the charging automatically goes to 500mA again. It could also be something else entirely; please supply a schematic.

Comment: @ocrdu you are right. So  "if, given time" how long should I wait or how can decrease this time. Also I am adding simple circuit.

Comment: I don't know how long the pre-charge takes; maybe it is in the datasheet. I doubt you can influence it. If you can confirm the normal charging does start after a while, let me know and I'll turn the comment into an answer.

Comment: @ocrdu well it did not charge the battery, almost I have waiting for 1 hour.  I was measuring the voltage of lipo battery it was decreasing slowly. ( I saw 1.8 Volt al least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well After read those [doc1](https://bikepixels.com/2019/11/10/how-to-add-a-lipo-battery-in-our-arduino-projects/), [doc2](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=134653.msg1012881#msg1012881) and [doc3](http://chanskingdom.blogspot.com/2015/12/arduino-uninterruptible-power-supply-ups.html). I've fixed my problem. maybe it will helps somebodey in the future. I've added 2 diodes and everting works perfectly, tested!
[image]